# Find a hamiltonian path in $T^{3}$

Tags: graph-theory, trees, hamiltonian-path

The cube of a graph $T$, denoted $T^{3}$, is the supergraph of $T$ such that the edge $(u, v)$ is in $T^{3}$ if and only if there is a path between $u$ and $v$ in $T$ with three or fewer edges.

My question is: given a tree $T$, how can we find a hamiltonian path on $T^{3}$

Comment: Suggested inductive statement: given a tree $T$ on $n>2$ vertices, for any edge $uv$ of $T$, there is a Hamiltonian *cycle* on $T^3$ which uses edge $uv$.

Comment: okey I edit it.  @MishaLavrov

Comment: I don't mean that as a correction to your question, but a hint for how to prove your original statement.

Comment: Sorry didn't get it, I don't see how we can male a hamiltonain path from your remark. (Note that I don't try to prove that a hamitonian path exsts, but I am tryig to construct it.@MishaLavrov)

Comment: If you have a cycle, then you can delete any edge from it and get a path.